# Pycharm - Type hints are not installed

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, type-hinting

I keep getting this warning in PyCharm 2018.3.5: "Type hints are not installed".

[image]

If I click 'Install', a log message like this appears:

> 6:11 PM   Packages installed successfully: Installed packages:
>   'djangorestframework-stubs'

But then the warning reappears in a few minues. How to fix it?
If it matters, I have a remote Docker Compose interpreter configured for the project, which is otherwise working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker about this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34624

What basically happens:

1. PyCharm finds `djangorestframework` installed and proposes to install a stub package for it as `djangorestframework-stubs` is missing
2. You click **Install**
3. PyCharm starts the container and installs `djangorestframework-stubs` there
4. PyCharm stops the container
5. Now `djangorestframework-stubs` is gone
6. Repeat from 1.

Comment: So if I was to install the package manually to a proper location, how would I go about it?

Comment: E.g. by updating your `Dockerfile` to install `djangorestframework-stubs`.